# "More Info" always "Fetching..." when I "Get Info" from a file

Tags: finder, macos, spotlight, ui

I'm having this issue with the "**More Info**" section of the **Info window** of a file (Cmd + I or "Get Info" in contextual menu):

[image]

I'm running Sierra 10.12.3, and I'm not sure when this started to happen, but it happens with all kind of files.

Any idea on how can I track the root problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Launch Services is at fault here. Rebuild or reset Launch Services using the technique [mentioned at this link](http://wccftech.com/fix-fetching-issue-mac-os-open-with-context-menu/). It worked for me a few weeks ago.

Comment: @IconDaemon I ran the command, but the issue is still present.

Comment: Did you restart the computer?

Comment: Yes, I just restarted my laptop. But it doesn't help :(

Comment: @IconDaemon finally the problem was that I had Spotlight disabled, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had **Spotlight** disabled. I disabled it because performance. I really never use it.

Would be great if Finder could get that metadata on the fly if it can't find them indexed.

To active Spotlight again:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

Comment: MDS is a low-level service used by much more than just Spotlight. It's a general indexing service for the file system and [any app can launch metadata queries](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmetadataquery), including Finder and Spotlight.